# How to set the session timeout after log in passportjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I want to set a session timeout after log in using passportjs. How to set the maxAge for the session using passportjs. What is the default max age for the session that passportjs provide?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is handled via Connect's session middleware, so for example:

```
.use(connect.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))
```

The [documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) has other useful bits that are worth reading for understanding session handling.

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the lifetime of the session cookie for express.session
like the following example:

```
app.use(express.session({
             secret : 'your_cookie_secret',
             cookie:{_expires : 60000000}, // time im ms
             })
        );
```

For testing I recommend a shorter expires time.

Comment: Can confirm that has worked for me, though I'd rather use a multiplication to express the time in ms to make it easier to change it in the future. Example: `cookie: { _expires: (10 * 60 * 1000) } // 10 minutes`

Answer (score 0):

Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

Got this using latest node toolchain... so this may not work anymore.