# passport js How do I configure how long someone stays logged in?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Can't seem to find anything in the docs at http://passportjs.org/ or anywhere else on how to properly set how long a user stays logged in.

I've currently got passport-local working on my dev machine, but I have no idea what the duration of a login will be and can't find anything about changing the setting.

Is this because it's set within express or something I'm missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991050/how-to-set-the-session-timeout-after-log-in-passportjs

Comment: on strategy callback, you can assign a field for example user.login_time = Date.now. It will be save database automatically by passport.onSerialize callback.

Comment: @damphat how is that useful though? it won't expire the session, nor will assigning a new value extend a session.

Comment: @robertklep you are right, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

As I thought might be the case, `passport` just uses `express`'s session config:

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'topsecret', cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 } }))
// login sessions last 1 hour
```

The cookie lasts `maxAge` milliseconds. There are many ways to set the cookie length; this was just the one that seemed simplest to me.