# session timeout in a nodejs + express app using setTimeOut( ) and a callback, and redirect the user to login page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, passport.js

I am trying to implement a session time out for a nodejs + express + passport app. I am using setTimeOut() to call a method where I am calling req.session.destroy() and req.logout() (for logging out passport session) to invalidate the session.

I am passing in the req and res to setTimeOut - setTimeOut(timeOutMethod, 10000, req, res). I see the session being set to null. I verified the request objects during different times, and they match.

I want to be able to call /logout endpoint in the timeOutMethod() (this is a callback for the setTimeOut()) or go back to the main page, but there will be no context. I can't use a res object to redirect the user. The app actually crashes at this point.

Is there anyway we can redirect or refresh the page so that user the sent back to the login screen?

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks a ton in advance!

:Code:

```
router.get(callback_url, passport.authenticate(login_strategy, {failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: '/page'}),
    function (req, res) {
        if(req && req.session){//max timeout is set to 1 min for testing...
            setTimeout(sessionTimeOut,  1 * 60 * 1000, req, res);
        }
        res.redirect('/');
    });

// a callback for session timeout...
function sessionTimeOut(req, res){
    if (req.session) {
        req.session.destroy(err => {
            if (err) {
              //log statements
            }
            else {
              //log statements
                if (req.user) {
                    //remove passport.js session user value if present
                    req.logout();
                }
            }
        });
        req.session = null;
    }
    else {
        //log statements
    }
    res.redirect('/page');
}

//error thrown when es.redirect('/page') as we don't have the context here.
_http_outgoing.js:561
[0]     throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
[0]     ^
[0]
[0] Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
```

Comment: Now that we've had a _description_ of the code, perhaps we could see the code? :)

Comment: Please share the code you've got so far

Comment: Thank you @JeremyThille I added the code details.

Comment: Thank you @Dupocas. I added the code details

Comment: Is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991050/how-to-set-the-session-timeout-after-log-in-passportjs) helpful?

Comment: @Dupocas, thank you for pointing me to the details. I tried the cookie maxAge option. This doesn't work for me. maxAge resets if there is any activity on the application. I am trying to log the user out after a certain time, regardless of the activity on the application

Comment: `res.redirect('/page')` probably doesn't do what you think. It does nothing in the browser. It's Node's internal routing, it reaches Express' `app.get("/page")` route. it happens only on the server and gives no instruction to the browser to change its URL and move to `/page`.

Comment: The req and res objects are specific to each request - you should not be doing anything with them outside of the context of the specific request being handled. If you need to use them with a timeout then that timeout should be triggered on the client side, which can then trigger a new request for you to be able to work with properly. HTTP is stateless, meaning if you need the server to be able to arbitrarily trigger something on the client you'll need to make use of something like websockets or long-polling.